# Wrapping code (listings, verbatim, or other method) inside a newcommand

Tags: macros, verbatim

For some teaching I've been doing, I'd like to have code from two different languages side-by-side.  To do so, I hacked together a `newcommand` which uses a `tabular` environment to arrange two `verb` environments, but the problems are myriad:

- Indentation can only be accomplished by changing spaces to ~'s
- Any math symbols have to be escaped with `\`, which requires knowing which ones to escape and which ones not to (can't escape the <'s for instance, otherwise it complains)
- The `<-` assignment operator gets changed into an upside down `!-` when compiled.

The `listings` environment doesn't work either.  Error message is:

```
Runaway argument?
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \lst@next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.23 \codeListing{x <- y}{f(g(x))}
```

Here's some code to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\codeListing}[2]{
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm} p{8cm}}
\begin{lstlisting}
#1
\end{lstlisting}
&
#2\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
}

\section{verbatim test}
\begin{verbatim}
logLik <- function(x) { 
  y <<- x^2+2
  return(sum(sqrt(y+7)))
}
\end{verbatim}

\section{codeListing test}
\codeListing{}{
logLik <- function(x) \{ 

~~y <<- x\^2+2

~~return(sum(sqrt(y+7)))

\}

}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to make a `newcommand` wrap parameter-passed code?  It doesn't have to be keyword-highlighted or do any of the other tricks that the fancier packages do; it just has to preserve whitespace and no interpret code as latex commands.

Comment: You might want to use a `minipage` or `parallel` environment. Note also that `listings` and `minted` (and a few others) are specialized in printing computer code (which is closer to your need than verbatim).

Comment: @Raphink I think I tried listings a few months ago but it didn't handle R code well?  Can't remember precisely.  I'll take a look at the others.  Thanks.

Comment: You can define unsupported language when using `listings` package. Read its manual by typing `texdoc listings` in your DOS prompt.

Comment: @xport Thanks for pointing that out.  It's been a few months since I tried making listings work but perhaps I'll give it another go.  Is there any reason to prefer `listings` over `minted` or any of the others?

Comment: I have not used `minted`. I use `showexpl` and `listings` packages. The former internally uses `listings`. I don't know why `minted` exists and what it wants to improve. :-)

Comment: @xport [`minted` was developed to improve on some problems with `listings` capacity to properly "understand" the code it was typesetting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966425/source-code-highlighting-in-latex)

Comment: @Seamus: OK. But I just tried it, but I got failed to compile it. No problem. :-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone so far.  I've edited the question to make it clear that I'd like code inside a newcommand environment.  The suggestions so far look great.  Going to leave it unchecked for a little while longer and see if anyone has any other creative ideas for my unholy machinations.

Comment: Please, take a look at the newest answer below. =)

Comment: See also [Verbatim inside a command - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83893/verbatim-inside-a-command?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We recently considered adding some support for verbatim arguments to `xparse`. Starting from roughly 15/08/2011 (on the svn, not yet on CTAN), you can define a command with any combination of optional, mandatory and verbatim arguments. Each command defined with `xparse` has an argument signature which indicates what kind of argument it expects (the most common are `m` for normal mandatory argument, `o` for optional, `s`, for an optional star). With the new argument type, for instance, `\verb` would have a signature `{sv}`: an optional star followed by a verbatim argument.

For your case, I think a good idea is to give the signature `{ O{} +v O{} +v }` to `\codeListing`:

- `#1`, optional argument = options given to the first listing (default empty);
- `#2`, verbatim argument = contents of the first listing;
- `#3`, optional argument = options given to the second listing (default empty);
- `#4`, verbatim argument = contents of the second listing;

The `+` mean that the next argument is "long". For non-verbatim arguments, this means that they may contain more than one paragraph. For verbatim arguments, it currently means that they may contain line-breaks, contrarily to the normal `\verb` command.

[Apart from the use of xparse, I based the example on Mike Renfro's answer.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\codeListing} { O{} +v O{} +v }
  {
    \begin{table}[h]\centering
      \begin{tabular}[width=\textwidth]{ll}
        \newlinechar=\endlinechar
        \exp_args:Nx \scantokens
          {
            \string\begin{lstlisting}[\unexpanded{#1}]
              #2
            \string\end{lstlisting}
            &
            \string\begin{lstlisting}[\unexpanded{#3}]
              #4
            \string\end{lstlisting}
          }
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\codeListing[language=C,backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30}]$
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
$[language=C++,backgroundcolor=\color{red!20}]$
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
$

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will break if one of the verbatim arguments includes a `}` won't it? Is there any plan to allow abritrary argument delimiters?

Comment: No wait, your example uses `$` as a delimiter. How?

Comment: @Seamus: it can use (almost) anything as a delimiter, like `\verb`. And the two verbatim arguments can use different delimiters. More precisely, in this case, `xparse` looks for an optional argument, tokenizing whichever token is next. Then the delimiter for the verbatim argument is that first token. Thus, the delimiter for the verbatim argument cannot be `%`, `\ `, space, `#`, `{`, nor `}`, but anything else (that doesn't appear in the argument you want) works.

Comment: `Unknown argument type 'v' replaced by 'm'. Fingers crossed ...`

That is what I get...

Comment: @KarelBilek Your installation of the `l3package` bundle (and probably `l3kernel` too is too old.  The verbatim argument type was added roughly a year ago.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from @xport's example, and minimizing it as much as possible, this is as close as I can get to the brevity of a two-argument command. Maybe someone else can take it the rest of the way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{K}{\lstset{language=C}}{}
\lstnewenvironment{M}{\lstset{language=C++}}{}
\newenvironment{T}{\begin{table}[h]\centering\begin{tabular}[width=\textwidth]{ll}}{\end{tabular}\end{table}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{T} \begin{K}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
\end{K} & \begin{M}
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
\end{M} \end{T}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Think about what things like `verbatim` and `listings` are doing. They are suspending LaTeX's normal reading of symbols and printing those symbols out directly. So `\verb~$~` says to LaTeX "Don't interpret anything up to the next "`~`"". That is, LaTeX reads `\verb` and then it says "OK, the next symbol signals the start of the verbatim text: I should search for the next instance of that symbol and ignore everything in between them". It then sees a "`~`", so it searches for the next matching symbol and doesn't interpret anything between them.
That's why `\verb~\end{document}~` doesn't end the document: LaTeX isn't interpreting those symbols that would normally signal the end of the document.

What you want to do with a `\newcommand` is going to be tricky. Things are being read in the wrong order. Look at the following:

```
\codeListing{$e^i$}{}
```

This becomes *e<sup>i</sup>*: not `$e^i$` as you want. The text isn't being ignored. That's why you're getting a lot of weird things going on.

Also, compare:

```
\codeListing{%}{}
\codeListing{}}{}
```

which both break, and:

```
\verb~%~
\verb~}~
```

which should work fine.

I think the "multiple environment" method of xport and Mike Renfro is as good as it gets here. You simply can't "hide" the verbatim commands inside new commands: LaTeX doesn't know what to do with them. Listings has to provide a new way of making new listings evnironments `\lstnewenvironment` because trying to put a `listings` inside a `\newenvironment` breaks...

Answer (score 4):

Please adapt the following until they suit your preferences.

[image]

### External `SourceCode.cs` file

```c
using System;
public class Foo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I Love LaTeX");//This is a comment.
    }
    /*This is a comment too.*/
}
```

### TeX input file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,cmyk,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\arrayrulewidth=\fboxrule
\tabcolsep=2\fboxsep
\arrayrulecolor{white}


\newcolumntype{A}[2]{%
    >{\begin{minipage}{%
        \dimexpr#2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-#1\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
        \vspace\tabcolsep}c<{\vspace\tabcolsep
    \end{minipage}}}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
    language=[Sharp]C,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=3,
    aboveskip=0\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    belowskip=-\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{Yellow!30},
    xleftmargin=0\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\color{Maroon}\scriptsize\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{Blue}\sf\bf,
    commentstyle=\color{Cyan},
    stringstyle=\color{Green},
    backgroundcolor=\color{Yellow!30}
}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longtable}{*2{|A{1.5}{0.45}}|}\hline
\lstinputlisting{SourceCode.cs}&\lstinputlisting{SourceCode.cs}\tabularnewline\hline
\lstinputlisting{SourceCode.cs}&\lstinputlisting{SourceCode.cs}\tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but the key part of my question is that I need it inside a `\newcommand` (and the code needs to be inline since I have dozens of 1-5 line snippets rather than a few large code files).

Comment: From section 5.1 of [the listings documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), it might not be worth it to even try to put the code into arguments. You'd have to modify your line breaks, spaces and tabs, special characters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One possible work around is to use a temporary file.

First you need a macro to write to the file (`\jobname.tmp` was used here) and read it twice using the *regular* and the `listing` input commands:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\newwrite\tempfile
\newcommand{\example}[1]{
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.tmp
    \immediate\write\tempfile{#1}
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile
    \input{\jobname.tmp}
    \lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}
}
```

Then use previous commands where you want to place the content. Notice that we have to use the `\unexpanded` macro.

```
\example{\unexpanded{\lipsum[1]}}
```

As shown in the following image that uses a method simular to the above one:

[image: tli]

Note: `lipsum` package must be used for the given example.