# How to stack boxes like a vertical version of \mbox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, boxes

I would like a vertical equivalent to `\mbox{}` that somehow takes a sequence of boxes and stacks them on top of each other.

I'd like the resulting width to be the width of the widest box, and I'd like it to have the following options:

- either no vertical space between the boxes or standard inter-line spacing
- left, right, or center alignment
- the baseline of the resulting box goes through one of the following:

  - top:  the baseline of the first box (like `\vtop`)
  - middle:  in the middle of the box
  - bottom:  the baseline of the last box (like `\vbox`)

For example:

```
surrounding text
\fbox{\stack[align=rt]{something}{something else}{foo}}
surrounding text
```

would produce:

```
                 +----------------+
surrounding text |      something | surrounding text
                 | something else |
                 |            foo |
                 +----------------+
```

Does something like this already exist?  If not, does anyone have any pointers about how to make it?

**Edit:**  I'm using LaTeX

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The v0.8 of `adjustbox` from 2011/11/14 has now a `\stackbox[<hor>][<vert>]{<content>}` macro (and a matching `stackbox` environment and `stack` key). It accepts vertical and horizontal alignment and uses the `varwidth` package internally.
To remove the usual skip between lines, you can use `\baselineskip=0pt` at the begin and `\par` at the end. I might add an option for this later.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

surrounding text
\fbox{\stackbox[r][t]{something\\something else\\foo}}
surrounding text

surrounding text
\fbox{\stackbox[l][b]{something\\something else\\foo}}
surrounding text

surrounding text
\adjustbox{stack=cc,fbox}{something\\something else\\foo}
surrounding text

% No interline skip:
surrounding text
\fbox{\stackbox[c][b]{\baselineskip=0pt something\\something else\\foo\par}}
surrounding text

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: as Leo Liu already pointed out it is a simple tabular

Comment: @Herbert: My first implementation try was using a `tabular`. However, like all other box macros of `adjustbox` the content is read as a real box to allow verbatim etc. This is actually quit difficult to do with an implicit `tabular`, so I went with `varwidth`. I also wanted to point out that there is a package which has a macro for this.

Comment: Thank you!  I like having something already written and debugged.  :)  Speaking of bugs, `\offinterlineskip` doesn't quite work with the macro variant (but the environment version works fine):  `\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\stackbox[r][t]{\offinterlineskip\fbox{something}\\\fbox{somethingelse}\\\fbox{foo}}`

Comment: @RichardHansen: You need to add a `\par` at the very end to make it work. I might add it in the macro definition in the next package version.

Comment: A warning here: `stackbox` doesn't allow its width to exceed `\linewidth`. This means that if you try and use a  `stackbox` inside an  `adjustbox`, it will not work correctly: your content can spill off the right hand side of the page. Using `tabular` instead seems to work... though I am nervous because I don't understand @Martin Scharrer 's point above.

Comment: @Mohan: `stackbox` uses paragraph mode for the contents, which leads to the limitation to `\linewidth`.

Answer (score 15):

It is strange no one has mentioned `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
before
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|}\firsthline
foo\\bar\\baz\\\lasthline
\end{tabular}
after

before
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}\firsthline
foo\\bar\\baz\\\lasthline
\end{tabular}
after
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can easily define a new command for short.

And there are indeed quite a lot of tool packages for tabulars to help you to get what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to control inter-row spacing with `tabular` (so that each box is stacked on top of each other with no vertical gaps)?

Comment: @RichardHansen: Yes, of course. The factor `\arraystretch` is for this. And you can use `makecell` package to modify the gape of the tabular lines.

Comment: Ah yes, `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}` eliminated all vertical space between the rows.  Excellent!

Comment: What are the pros and cons of using `tabular` vs. the `varwidth` approach?  Is one better than the other with respect to compatibility (with other LaTeX commands or packages)?

Comment: @Richard: Well, you know a `varwidth` is a `minipage` with variable width, in fact origin `\parbox` or `minipage` is enough in most cases. A `tabular` is actually more complex and more powerful than a minipage box: alignment, spacing, frames, etc.

Comment: What about a verbatim environment?

Comment: @Richard: `tabular` itself support `\verb` in it. But you cannot define a macro that support `\verb` in the arguments. Anyway, `cprotect` package would help. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/wrapping-code-listings-verbatim-or-other-method-inside-a-newcommand

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question but it has a very easy *decomplexified* answer, which I offer here for completeness. Use `\valign` from TeX.

Then it becomes a two liner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Before text \lower 30pt\hbox{\valign{&\hbox to 1cm{\fbox{#}\hfil}\vfill\cr
one& two& three& four& five& six\cr}} after text.
\end{document}
```

TeX commands are available in (La)TeX, and these are the commands that LaTeX uses to build its own macros. I have used `\fbox` from LaTeX, but is as easy to define a `boxit` command using TeX. (Please also see the alternative solution by morbusg in the comments, using `ooalign`).

[image]

Comment: Maybe even `Before text \oalign{one\cr two\cr three\cr four\cr} after text.`?

Comment: @morbusg -- Thanks I forgot about this! Even simpler. I don't know why people don't use basic TeX more.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an option that uses the [`keyval` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval) for setting the keys, the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) for setting the text block, the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) for line height adjustment and [`xifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) for conditioning.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\usepackage{keyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stack}[2][,]{%
  \setkeys{stack}{#1}% Set keys
  \begin{varwidth}[\stack@valign]{\textwidth}\stack@spacing\stack@halign#2\end{varwidth}%
}
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@key{stack}{halign}{% horizontal alignment
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{r}}{\def\stack@halign{\raggedleft}}{% right-aligned
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{c}}{\def\stack@halign{\centering}}{% centered
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{l}}{\def\stack@halign{\raggedright}}{% left-aligned
  }}}% Otherwise, justified
}
\define@key{stack}{valign}{% vertical alignment
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{m}}{\def\stack@valign{m}}{% middle-aligned
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{\def\stack@valign{b}}{% bottom-aligned
    \def\stack@valign{t}}}% top-aligned
}
\define@key{stack}{spacing}{\def\stack@spacing{#1}}% spacing
\makeatother
% ========= KEY DEFAULTS =========
\setkeys{stack}{halign=l,valign=t,spacing=\setstretch{1}}%

\begin{document}
surrounding text
\fbox{\stack[valign=m]{something\par something else\par foo}}%
surrounding text

surrounding text
\fbox{\stack[valign=b,halign=l]{something\par something else\par foo}}%
surrounding text

surrounding text
\fbox{\stack[valign=t,halign=r]{something\par something else\par foo}}%
surrounding text

surrounding text
\fbox{\stack[valign=m,halign=c]{something\par something else\par foo}}%
surrounding text

surrounding text
\fbox{\stack[valign=t,spacing=\doublespacing]{something\par something else\par foo}}%
surrounding text

surrounding text
\fbox{\stack[valign=b,halign=c,spacing=\onehalfspacing]{something\par something else\par foo}}%
surrounding text
\end{document}
```

The following key-value pairs are defined:

- `valign`: Adjusts the vertical alignment; possible options are `t`op (default), `m`iddle and `b`ottom. Anything else specified defaults to `t`op.
- `halign`: Adjusts the horizontal alignment; possible options are `l`eft or `\raggedright` (default), `c`enter or `\centering`, and `r`ight or `\raggedleft`. Anything else defaults to justified text.
- `spacing`: Provides an additional formatting hook. With the `setspace` package loaded, one could use `\doublespacing` or `\setstretch{2}`, say. Turning off the inter-line skip is done using `spacing=\offinterlineskip` or `spacing={\baselineskip=0pt}`.

Note @barbarabeeton's comment regarding `\offinterlineskip`:

> `\offinterlineskip` has the danger that if some lines contain no
>   ascenders or no descenders, the baselines can become very irregular.
>   Very ugly and undesirable. use `\strut`, or less intrusive,
>   `$\mathstrut$` (since it doesn't include leading), to even them out if
>   you must use this option.

Comment: Another good answer!  I have the same question:  How would I turn off inter-line spacing?  Thanks!

Comment: I think I figured it out:  `spacing=\offinterlineskip` seems to do it.

Comment: \offinterlineskip has the danger that if some lines contain no ascenders or no descenders, the baselines can become very irregular.  very ugly and undesirable.  use \strut, or less intrusive, $\mathstrut$ (since it doesn't include leading), to even them out if you must use this option.

Comment: Sometimes I intentionally want the baselines to be irregular.  Not often, but often enough that I'd like it to be an option.

Comment: @RichardHansen: Agreed, this is down to personal preference and the application of the provided solution (not always included in the original question), and therefore very subjective at times.

Answer (score 6):

### Basic Solution:

You can use a `node` with `tikz`. Below I have defined a macro that accepts an optional alignment as either `top`, `middle`, or `bottom` alogn with 3 parameters for the various text fields.  You can easily extend this to handle more.

```
\MyVBox[top|middle|bottom]{text1}{text2}{text3}
```

Using just these basic alignment positions you get:

[image]

### Fancy Options:

But, since this is using `\tikz` you can also get fancier and adjust the alignment to center, left, add a fill, specify a color for the lines, use a dashed line, etc, etc:

[image]

### Further Enhancements:

In this solution I resorted to magic numbers for `yshift` that had to be tweaked to get the `top` and `middle` alignment options to work properly. However if the vertical size of the bounding box changes by adjusting the `inner sep` or the line thickness, this will need to be tweaked. I attempted to use the `use as bounding box` option as well as adjust those parameters automatically but was not able to get it to work as I expected.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{top/.style={baseline={([yshift=-2.44ex]current bounding box.north)}}}
\tikzset{middle/.style={baseline={([yshift=-0.80ex]current bounding box.west)}}}
\tikzset{bottom/.style={baseline=(X.base)}}

\newcommand{\MyVBox}[4][middle, align=right]{\tikz [#1] \node [draw=black, align=right, #1] (X) {#2 \\ #3 \\ #4};}%
\begin{document}
surrounding text
    \MyVBox[top]{something}{something else}{foo}
surrounding text

surrounding text
    \MyVBox[middle]{something}{something else}{foo}
surrounding text

surrounding text
    \MyVBox[bottom]{something}{something else}{foo}
surrounding text

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
surrounding text
    \MyVBox[middle,align=center,draw=blue,fill=yellow]{something}{longer something else}{foo}
surrounding text

surrounding text
    \MyVBox[middle,align=left,draw=red,fill=green, dashed]{something}{even longer something else}{foo}
surrounding text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Do you know how I might turn off the inter-line space?

Comment: It seems like tikz is powerful enough that it should be possible to specify which line's baseline the entire box's baseline should go through.  I wonder how hard it would be to tweak the macro to make it possible to specify a line number to use as the baseline?  For example, `baseline=1` would be the same as giving the `top` option, `baseline=2` would align to the second line's baseline, `baseline=-1` would be the same as `bottom`, `baseline=-2` would select the baseline of the second-to-last line as the box's baseline, etc.

Comment: I believe the the inter-line spacing is the normal spacing between lines in a paragraph, so adjusting that should do the job. Yeah, I agree that `tikz` can probably do that, I just am not that much of an expert to be able to do it without much work.  You can post a follow up question about that and am pretty sure you'll get a great solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is a ConTeXt solution:

```
\starttext
surrounding text
\inframed [align=left, location=top]
  {something\\something else\\foo}
surrounding text
\stoptext
```

the result looks like this:
[image: result]

> left, right, or center alignment

Use the `align` key: `left`, `middle`, or `right`.

The baseline position is controlled by the `location` key. Set it to either `top`, `bottom`, `middle`. The baseline distance can be controlled using something like

```
\inframed [
  align=left,
  location=top,
  top={\setupinterlinespace[18pt]}]
  {something\\something else\\foo}
```

You can remove the frame with `frame=off`.
There are many more options to tweak look [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Reference/en/setupframed) or [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Framed) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using LaTeX.