# \newcommand to make a plot command using gnuplottex

Tags: macros, gnuplot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrapping code (listings, verbatim, or other method) inside a newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/wrapping-code-listings-verbatim-or-other-method-inside-a-newcommand)

I'm new to LaTeX and trying to write a command to plot files using the `gnuplottex` package (and `gnuplot`).

For now I am doing this (and it works):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf,scale=1]
    plot 'testfile' using 1:2
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to do is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\newcommand{\plotdata}[1]
{
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf,scale=1]
        plot '#1' using 1:2
    \end{gnuplot}
}

\begin{document}
\plotdata{testfile} % this is the goal
\end{document}
```

But the build fails in the second case due to gnuplot errors (it fails to produce plots).

I'm using TeXLive/Ubuntu. Any ideas, why it does not work (or how I can see the code generated after `\newcommand` macros execution)?

Comment: What are the errors? What does `#1` mean? Where should it come from?

Comment: For your last question, use `\show\plotdata`.

Comment: The problem is that the contents of the `gnuplot` environment are scanned like a `verbatim`. Putting verbatim-like environments into a command usually runs into problems. I don't know any workarounds, but maybe someone else can pick up from here.

Comment: See also http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin