# Macro with lstlisting inside

Tags: listings, xparse

I have been following [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/wrapping-code-listings-verbatim-or-other-method-inside-a-newcommand) about using `\NewDocuentCommand` with `lstlisting` and the accepted answer is nice except it is too big and it doesn't quite work for me.

I came up with this example to test `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{m +v}{
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=#1,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm]
        #2
    \end{lstlisting}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
   
\begin{document}

\code{C}{
int x = 200;
unsigned int y = 0;
}

\end{document}
```

Like stated in the [CTAN xparse documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) I first used `m` as a normal parameter and then `+v` as a multiline verbatim parameter, but it fails. It looks like I am still missing something...

Comment: You cannot wrap verbatim into macros.  This doesn't change with LaTeX3.

Comment: Use `\lstnewenvironment` instead.

Comment: @Henri Menke I need to create a command and not environment. In the example I provided they did it somehow...

Comment: @71GA you didn't provide an example: I guess you forgot to add the link…

Comment: @clemens Sorry. There it is.

Comment: You can't use the v-argument for a multiline argument. It will complain with `! Verbatim argument of '\code ' ended by end of line.`.

Comment: Ok so I changed v to `+v` and it won't work.

Comment: @71GA »I need to create a command...« Wrong! You *want* to create a command but what you need and should use is an environment.

Comment: @Henri Menke I am working on a document which should be as easy as possible for the end user to input commands and it is easier for them to write `\kodaB{C}{...}` than `\begin{kodaB}...\end{kodaB}`.

Comment: @71GA I highly doubt that.

Comment: @71GA it isn't easier to use a command than an environment, just different. In this case, especially when the code part spans several lines, an environment IMHO is both easier to input *and* makes the document source easier to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use Bruno's solution from the linked question (pretty smart I think).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{m +v}{
  \newlinechar=\endlinechar
  \exp_args:Nx \scantokens
  {
    \string\begin{lstlisting}[\unexpanded{language=#1,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm}]
      #2
    \string\end{lstlisting}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\code{C}{
int x = 200;
unsigned int y = 0;
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But please, just use a new environment instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1]{\lstset{language=#1,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}{C}
int x = 200;
unsigned int y = 0;
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Output is similar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more thing is bugging me. In either of the cases you provided, code is moved one tab to the right if I move source code `\begin{code}...\end{code}` one tab right. So source code position affects the compiled code position. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @71GA See the `gobble` option in the documentation.

Comment: @ Henri Menke In the first solution, if the content of the second argument(+v) locates at the same line where `\code{` is, this part of content will not be typeset. Why and how to deal with that?

Comment: @lyl `lstlisting` environment ignores the content on its first line as well, so no surprise here. To deal with it insert an explicit `^^J` at the end of the lines.

Comment: @user202729 I tried with the above example of the first solution like this  `... unsigned int y = 0; ^^J`, but only get `... unsigned int y = 0; ^^J`

Comment: @lyl No, insert in the command definition. Ensure that the ^^J get catcode other. \iow_newline: works as well.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you for this wonderful proposal! And `\code{% ...` causes error. Why and how to do that?

Comment: @HenriMenke You forgot the `\newlinechar=\endlinechar`. (fortunately lstlisting happily ignores it in this case)

Comment: @lyl Because of the above.

Comment: @user202729 @HenriMenke It seems that combination of `\newlinechar=\endlinechar` and `^^J` causes error. And `\code{% ...` causes the first line(`int x = 200;`) disappear.

Comment: @lyl Do understand what code does instead of just test out random things. By default xparse uses char 13 to separate lines, but to write to file/scantokens you need char \newlinechar which is 10 by default. Anyway "how to keep first line" isn't really in the focus of this question.