# Conditionally display lstlisting

Tags: listings, conditionals, expl3, latex3, exercises

I'm writing a documentclass for creating exercise sheets and exams at school. For this purpose I created a boolean variable `\g_test_showresults_bool` which can be used to conditionally display the solutions/results of the exercises, so I can create one document without results for the students and one with the results for me.

I already created such a environment for "normal" content (text, math) but I am not able to create one for listings. I tried the solutions explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376041/macro-with-lstlisting-inside) but without success. I also found `\lstnewenvironment`, but I don't know how to include my boolean `\g_test_showresults_bool` here.

Here is my current template. I would also appreciate a macro instead of an environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \g_test_showresults_bool
\bool_set_eq:NN \g_test_showresult_bool \c_true_bool

\NewDocumentEnvironment { reslstlisting } { } {

}{

}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

% Display this listing only if \g_test_showresults_bool is true
\begin{reslstlisting}
float i;
i = i + 6;
\end{reslstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see an advantage of an `expl3` `\bool` -'variable' over a traditional `\newif\ifshowresult` and `\showresulttrue` and `\showresultfalse` usage here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In the real documentclass I work with `l3keys` and tried to focus to the usage of LaTeX3. A solution compatible with `l3keys` would also be helpful.

Comment: `l3keys` also sets booleans. But your main problem is to produce the verbatim environment. Maybe you should search for a way to do that. Btw: Why don't you use one of the existing exercise packages?

Comment: @TeXnician I already tried to create a conditionally displayed verbatim (see the link I've added) for hours, but without success. That's why I am asking for help here.

Comment: See the `xsim` (specifically package `xsimverb`) manual page 50/51. That would support verbatim/listings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an adapted version from the `xsimverb` manual, which does the job for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsimverb,listings}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_test_showresults_bool
\bool_set_eq:NN \g_test_showresult_bool \c_true_bool
\NewDocumentEnvironment{reslstlisting}{}{%
    \XSIMsetfilebegin{\@percentchar\space file `\jobname.tmp'}
    \XSIMsetfileend{\@percentchar\space bye bye}
    \XSIMfilewritestart{\jobname.tmp}
}{
    \XSIMfilewritestop
    \bool_if:NT \g_test_showresult_bool
        {
            \lstinputlisting[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]{\jobname.tmp}
        }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Listing:
    \begin{reslstlisting}
bla bla \LaTeX
    \end{reslstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works great, thanks! An addition (which can be found at the `xsimverb` manual): `\XSIMsetfilebegin`and `\XSIMsetfileend` add the specified content to the listing. I removed them, because I didn't need it.

Comment: @dawu I just did c&p with minimal modifications...

Comment: No problem! I just wanted to point out for other readers that these lines aren't necessary.