# Reuse style of code listing in Beamer

Tags: beamer, listings

I add Prolog code to my slides like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}

% No navigation symbols at the bottom of each slide
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.89}

\begin{document}

\defverbatim[colored]\lstMiaFood{
\begin{mdframed}[
    frametitle=mia.pl,
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=light-gray!30,
    backgroundcolor=light-gray,
    roundcorner=2pt,
    leftmargin=1,
    rightmargin=1,
    innerleftmargin=1,
    innertopmargin=1,
    innerbottommargin=1,
    outerlinewidth=2,
    linecolor=gray
  ]

  \begin{lstlisting}[
    language=Prolog,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
  ]
likes(mia, Food) :- isItalian(Food).

likes(mia, Food) :- isAmerican(Food),
                    isVegetarian(Food).
isItalian(pizza).
isItalian(lasagna).
isItalian(spaghetti).

isAmerican(frenchFries).
isAmerican(hamburger).
isAmerican(macaroniAndCheese).

isVegetarian(frenchFries).
isVegetarian(macaroniAndCheese).

  \end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
}

\frame{
  \frametitle{Test code}
  \lstMiaFood
}

\end{document}
```

This works fine and produces slides like these:

[image: slide with code]

I'd like to reuse the style of the listing and the frame which is why I tried to define a `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\prologCode}[1]{
  \defverbatim[colored]\lstMiaFood{
    \begin{mdframed}[
        frametitle=mia.pl,
        frametitlerule=true,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=light-gray!30,
        backgroundcolor=light-gray,
        roundcorner=2pt,
        leftmargin=1,
        rightmargin=1,
        innerleftmargin=1,
        innertopmargin=1,
        innerbottommargin=1,
        outerlinewidth=2,
        linecolor=gray
      ]
      \begin{lstlisting}[
        language=Prolog,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}
      ]
{#1}
      \end{lstlisting}
    \end{mdframed}
  }
}
```

But this errors with:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang2.sty)
Runaway argument?
{ 
! Paragraph ended before \\lstlisting@ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                  \par 
l.94 }
```

Is there a way around this error to reuse the listing and frame style?

---

## Regarding this question being a duplicate

I'm aware of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376041/macro-with-lstlisting-inside#376045) but its two solutions both produce compilation errors with the MWE I provided above:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: The verbatim command '\code' cannot be used inside an
(LaTeX3)        argument.
```

is produced by

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{m +v}{
  \exp_args:Nx \scantokens
  {
    \string\begin{lstlisting}[\unexpanded{language=#1,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm}]
      #2
    \string\end{lstlisting}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\frame{
  \frametitle{Test code}
    \code{C}{
    int x = 200;
    unsigned int y = 0;
    }
}
\end{document}
```

and

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 110
```

results from

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1]{\lstset{language=#1,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm}}{}

\begin{document}
\frame{
  \frametitle{Test code}
    \begin{code}{C}
    int x = 200;
    unsigned int y = 0;
    \end{code}
}
\end{document}
```