# Why solutions for macros with lstlisting inside fail if tabulation in the verbatim text?

Tags: macros, expl3, verbatim

For instance [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376045/18401) for macros with `lstlisting` inside works well, except if the verbatim text contains a tabulation (as shown by the following MCE). Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{m +v}{
  \exp_args:Nx \scantokens
  {
    \string\begin{lstlisting}[\unexpanded{language=#1,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm}]
      #2
    \string\end{lstlisting}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Works well}

\code{C}{
Foo bar
}

\section{Fails}

\code{C}{
Foo	bar
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Joseph said "it's not a priority" https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60060617#60060617 ... although if you make pull request to https://github.com/latex3/latex3/pulls it might be accepted. No guarantee though

Comment: By the way it's possible to include literal tab character in SE post (<pre><code>&#9;</code></pre>), however it's quite messy -- if I definitely need it I would probably go to https://tio.run/ pick any language, then use its "generate code" feature.

Comment: @user202729 (Off topic) I can't see the point of tio.run but that's not a big deal :)

Comment: (also off topic) I mean, so that you don't have to manually (/with a regex) replace every tab with `&#9;` and every < with `&lt;`, in case you want to include a tab character in the code. It's not the main purpose of the site but can be (ab) used to do that

Answer (score 2):

`\dospecials`, which sets the special catcodes for verbatim environments, doesn't include a tab character (`^^I`).  TeX then treats the tab as a regular space, and upon seeing that, the verbatim scanner complains.  You can add `\do\^^I` to `\dospecials` to make it work (in the code below I added it in a group so it has no effect outside your command):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \code { }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_put_right:Nn \dospecials { \do \^^I }
      \code_aux:nw
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \code_aux:nw { m +v }
  {
      \exp_args:Nx \scantokens
        {
          \string\begin{lstlisting}[\unexpanded
            {language=#1,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm}]
            #2
          \string\end{lstlisting}
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Works well}

\code{C}{
Foo bar
}

\section{Fails (a tabulation is supposed to be between "Foo" and "bar")}

\code{C}{
Foo	bar
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: P.S.: Don't use tabs :)

Comment: Hm I notice you posted an answer there, I think it's better to encloses as duplicate though – you get list of cross-links to relevant questions on the main one (right sidebar) & if there's something new people don't have to copy paste answer on every question & etc. (basically every reason why duplicate feature was created on SO)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You cannot guarantee users of your macros won't use tabs ;)

Comment: @user202729 Yes, good that you found a suitable duplicate (and I don't object closing), but not always people remember/find a duplicate before posting an answer (and I definitely didn't remember to look at the sidebar :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Unfortunately, indeed! ;-)  That was more of a rant than a serious comment :)

Comment: Well maybe it's just me who spends extraordinary effort to look for duplicate before writing an answer... but then writing answer isn't free of cost too && you get better linking ↑

Answer (score 1):

Besides the circumstance that +v-preprocessing of arguments does not take care of the character code of the horizontal tab-character (`^^I` in TeX's `^^`-notation), so that horizontal tabs even with v/+v-type-arguments usually are tokenized as explicit space-tokens of category 10(space) and character code 32 while v/+v-arguments deliberately are implemented to trigger error-messages in case of containing explicit space-tokens, I suggest not to use  `\exp_args:Nx` because that might lead to unwanted expansion of active characters in case of using inputenc. Instead you can use a scratch-macro which reads the phrases `\begin{lstlistig}` and `\end{lstlisting}` under modified catcode-régime and then defines the non-scratch-variant.

And you might wish to have the `\newline`-character-mechanism neutralized, by temporarily giving `\newlinechar` the value of `\endlinechar`, while `\scantokens` does its writing of the fake-file—in order to make sure  the `lstlisting`-environment and your `\code`-command behave in the same way even when someone played around with the `\newlinechar`-parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{m}{
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_other:N \^^I
  \innercode{#1}
}
\group_begin:
\NewDocumentCommand{\innercode}{mmm}{
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand{\innercode}{m +v}{
    \group_end:
    \group_begin:
    % See the subtle difference between \code and the lstlisting-environment
    % when turning the following line into a comment:
    \tex_newlinechar:D=\tex_endlinechar:D
    %
    \tex_scantokens:D
    {
      #3
      #1[language=##1,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm]%
        ##2
      #2%<-here \scantokens attaches an endline-chracter=return
    }
  }
}
\use:n{
  \char_set_catcode_other:N \\
  \char_set_catcode_other:N \{
  \char_set_catcode_other:N \}
  \char_set_catcode_group_begin:N \[
  \char_set_catcode_group_end:N \]
  \innercode
}[\begin{lstlisting}][\end{lstlisting}][\endgroup~]

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Works well}

\code{C}{
Foo bar
}

\section{A tabulation is supposed to be between "Foo" and "bar"}

\newlinechar=`\A

\code{C}{
Foo	bar
Foo	bar
Foo	bar
Foo	barAFoo  bar
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,numbers=none,xleftmargin=0.35cm,framesep=0mm]
Foo	bar
Foo	bar
Foo	bar
Foo	barAFoo  bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't imagine weird stuff as `\group_begin:
\NewDocumentCommand{\innercode}{mmm}{
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand{\innercode}{m +v}{` could be possible :)

Comment: I couldn't any difference between the cases `% \tex_newlinechar:D=-1~` and `\tex_newlinechar:D=-1~`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Comment/disable both `\tex_newlinechar:D=\tex_endlinechar:D` and  `\tex_newlinechar:D=-1~`  so that the `\newlinechar`-mechanism is enabled and you see a difference between what is delivered by the `\code`-command and what is delvered by the `lstlisting`-environment: In the one case you get the last line `Foo   BarAFoo  Bar`, in the other case the `A` is not there but the string is split in two lines at this place.