# Commands around minted or comment environment

Tags: minted, comments

I am trying to manipulate minted code inside my custom defined macros, however I am getting an error `File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine`. A similar thing happens with comments as well which I suspect has a similar reason (though they are less important to me).

Here's a minimum (non-) working example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{comment}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytestCmd}{+m}{% a trivial command
  #1}

\newenvironment{mytestEnv}{}{} % a trivial environment

\begin{document}

\mytestCmd   % commenting this removes the error
{
\begin{minted}{py}
  u = rand()
\end{minted}
}

\mytestCmd   % commenting this removes the error
{
\begin{comment}
  My comment
\end{comment}
}

\begin{mytestEnv}  % Environments work without issue, but not macros
\begin{minted}{py}
  u = rand()
\end{minted}
\begin{comment}
  My comment
\end{comment}
\end{mytestEnv}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get minted and comment environments to work as arguments for macros?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: A bit longer answer: Yes, but not in a way that you could use that inside a macro's argument, so in total: no.

Comment: Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/wrapping-code-listings-verbatim-or-other-method-inside-a-newcommand/25753#25753

Comment: I found [cprotect](https://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect) which seems to work in this simple case.